# Unable to start Apache and MySQL servers in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, installation, xampp

I am getting some issue with the installation of xampp in windows. Actually I have skype and team viewer installed in my laptop. I have uninstalled team viewer and in skype I have checked off the "use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections" Still I am getting this problem. which is

```
5:07:24 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL"!
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
5:07:32 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Both MySql and Apache are not starting. Pls help me with this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You've already got MySQL running somehow. Find out where that is and turn it off.

Comment: Thnq.. But how to find out that where it is running..

Comment: Look in your process listing, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says: you are running MYSQL from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld`

You can go Windows logo > type `services.msc` > Search for Mysql Service and stop it. (left pannel "Stop")

[image]

**NOTE**: If you are going to use XAMPP, you should remove any previous installation of apache, php and/or mysql